# Validate email without dot(.) at starting in HTML pattern

Tags: html

I have validated email with proper @ and .com availbale in the email address by using  but its not validating whether the email address has dot(.) at starting point (For example: .john@gmail.com).

Actually while creating account in gmail it will check whether the choosed address has dot at starting point of the address i want same as like that.

I have tried like below but its not working

```
<input type="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" title="Enter valid email address" name="email" required class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email is here...">
```

Can anyone give me an idea to achieve this....?

Comment: This email regular expression is woefully inadequate. `x@google` is theretically a valid email address, as is `ロボット@example.com`. Has the world gone mad? Maybe, but that's the world we live in. The only thing you can realistically test for is that it has an `@` in it. Beyond that the only way to know for sure is to attempt delivery. Your pattern will reject even mundane addresses like `BobJones@example.com` and `example@example.info`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use not operator (`^`) .

Here is your regxr: `^[^(\.)][a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}`

Comment: The `pattern` attribute has implicit anchors. What is `[^(\.)]` supposed to do?